# It is possible to somehow use forward_missing_to to fetch/set hash values?

Tags: crystal-lang

I am building client for Asterisk Manager (AMI), which sending back "events" (strings in key-value format). Depending on event type the keys are different. Some known would be defined similar as a `property`, but I also want to access everything else similar way (I need only getter).

Below is example and I am confused about `forward_missing_to`, to fetch hash value (i.e. `e.foo => e.data["foo"]` and `e.foo? => e.data["foo"]?`

```
class Event
  @data = Hash(String,String).new

  def initialize(data : Hash(String, String))
    @data.merge! data
  end

  # known field (event), here I could apply various validations etc.
  def event=(@name : String)
    @data["name"] = @name
  end

  def event : String
    @data["name"].not_nil!
  end

  # Confusing about this:
  forward_missing_to @data
end
```

Example of usage:

```
e = Event.new({"event" => "Test", "foo" => "bar"})
p e.event    # => "Test" (only this works)
p e.foo      # => expecting to get "bar"
p e.unknown  # => should throw Unhandled exception: Missing hash key: "unknown" (KeyError)
p e.unknown? # => nil
```

Answer (score 4):

`forward_missing_to` just means this:

```
e = Event.new({"event" => "Test", "foo" => "bar"})

# Same as invoking `foo` on the @data instance variable
# because you said forward_missing_to @data
e.foo
```

It doesn't mean invoking `["foo"]` on `@data`.

You can do it like this:

```
  macro method_missing(call)
    {% if call.args.empty? && !call.named_args %}
      @data[{{call.name.stringify}}]
    {% else %}
      {% raise "undefined method '#{call.name}' for #{@type}" %}
    {% end %}
  end
```

However, I wouldn't advise using `method_missing`, mainly because it might be eventually removed from the language (together with `forward_missing_to`).